# Calling Python function from angular button and displaying output video in video tag

Tags: python, angular, video-streaming, integration

I am new with Angular and have no idea what I am supposed to do to resolve this problem. In my code, there is an HTML 5 video tag and a button. when the button is clicked, a python code is supposed to perform an operation on live video and stream it to the web API that I am supposed to develop. This streamed video is to be shown through the video tags.

I must use angular for the front-end and I am supposed to tell the python developer what I need from him. If video tags are not right way of doing this, I could change that. For reference, I have posted my HTML code here. Also, the button click must pass an integer value to the python code, which I am assuming would be by calling a function with an argument. Please guide.

`Start

`

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar things by using this, but in vanilla javascript. When the button is clicked my index function in python Flask get executed.

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href='/'">Home</button>`

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot say that I am absolutely clear what you mean. Please also do remember that these are two separate APIs that need to work together.